# Casper JS run method firing early

Tags: javascript, casperjs

The addition of a this.echo command to a function is causing the casper.run method to be called before the links have been set

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

function getLinks() {
  this.echo("Getting links"); // <--------- This line cause everything to fail
  var links = document.querySelectorAll('table');
  return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(e) {
    return e.getAttribute('id');
  });
}

var links = [];

casper.start('example.html', function() {
  links = this.evaluate(getLinks);
});

casper.run(function() {
  this.echo(links.length + ' links found:');
  this.echo(' - ' + links.join('\n - ')).exit();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never worked with casper.js, but from the [**documentation**](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate):

> As a reminder, think of the `evaluate()` method as a gate between the CasperJS environment and the one of the page you have opened; everytime you pass a closure to `evaluate()`, you’re entering the page and execute code as if you were using the browser console.

So, `this` probably doesn't refer to `casper`, but to the global object of the document. `this.echo` doesn't exist and throws an error, the rest of the function is not executed and no links are collected. So, it's not that the callback function passed to `run` is executed early, the code to collect the links just never runs.

Try `casper.echo("Getting links");` instead, or simply remove the call and move it inside `start`:

```
casper.start('example.html', function() {
  this.echo("Getting links");
  links = this.evaluate(getLinks);
});
```